# webpack with Typescript, how to create a module to be used as a plugin for other consumers

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, umd

According to the docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

configuring the output like this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    library: 'someLibName',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'someLibName.js',
    auxiliaryComment: 'Test Comment'
  }
};
```

should output something like this:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
  // Test Comment
  if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory(require('lodash'));
  // Test Comment
  else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define(['lodash'], factory);
  // Test Comment
  else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports['someLibName'] = factory(require('lodash'));
  // Test Comment
  else
    root['someLibName'] = factory(root['_']);
})(this, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_1__) {
  // ...
});
```

to be able to use this module by any other consumer.

However in my case the output is something like:

```
!function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t(require("React")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("lib",["React"],t):"object........"
```

I am using typescript instead of plain javascript, what I am missing or doing wrong?

I am using webpack "^4.27.1",

This is my webpack.config.prod.js

```
    const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        //path: resolve(__dirname, 'umd'),
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: 'lib.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'lib',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        auxiliaryComment: 'Test Comment'
        //globalObject: 'this'
    },
    // output: {
    //     filename: "bundle.js",
    //     path: __dirname + "/dist"
    // },

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins:[
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    ],

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. The output seems to be exactly as it should be, only with some variables renamed, whitespace removed, and `()` around IIFE replaced with `!`. These differences are insignificant.

Comment: But the point of making libraryTarget: 'umd' is to generate UMD for this module to be consumed by other modules, however webpackUniversalModuleDefinition is not in the generated code. How do I use that code now in the consumer module?

Comment: For example, if I do a search of 'Test Comment' in the generated code, I cannot find it

Comment: The name of the function and the comments do not affect the ability of the consumers to use the module. Comments were probably removed by the same process in your build setup that removed the white space.